# Почему не отображаются CTkFrame на CtkScrollableFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

У меня проблема, не отображаются виджеты на CtkScrollableFrame / Customtkinter. Помогите пожалуйста решить, вот часть кода:
import ctypes
import json

```
import cpuinfo
import customtkinter as ctk
import keyboard
import psutil
import pywinstyles
from PIL import Image

from open_json import *

# Open settings.json
settings = open_on_read('settings.json')

colors = settings['Colors'][settings['Theme']]
# Color depending
text_color = colors['text']
hover_color = colors['hover']
active_color = colors['active']
frame_color = colors['main_frame']
menu_frame_color = colors['menu_frame']
transparent_color = 'transparent'

class AppsLogFrame(ctk.CTkScrollableFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        # добавление виджетов на фрейм
        for i, proc in enumerate(psutil.process_iter()):
            process_name = proc.name()

            self.app_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(
                master=self,  # Измените master на self.interior
                width=400,
                height=50,
                corner_radius=7,
                border_width=0,
                fg_color='#212121',
                bg_color='transparent'
            )
            self.app_name_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.app_frame,
                text=process_name,
                text_color=text_color
            )

            self.app_frame.place(y=i*50, x=20)
            self.app_name_label.place(y=25, x=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам нашёл решение, оказывается этот виджет не поддерживает метод размещения place и я использовал grid:

```
class AppsLogFrame(ctk.CTkScrollableFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        # добавление виджетов на фрейм
        for i, proc in enumerate(psutil.process_iter()):
            process_name = proc.name()
            if process_name != '':
                self.app_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(
                    master=self,
                    width=595,
                    height=50,
                    corner_radius=7,
                    border_width=0,
                    fg_color='#212121',
                    bg_color='transparent'
                )
                self.app_name_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
                    self.app_frame,
                    text=process_name,
                    text_color=text_color
                )

                self.app_frame.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=2) # Изменить на grid
                self.app_name_label.place(y=25, x=20)
```